# Python tabula returns the 'attributeError: module 'tabula' has no attribute 'read_pdf''

Tags: python, pdf, attributeerror, tabula, pdf-scraping

I working with `Tabula` to do some pdf scraping. 
However, when I run the:

**`tables = tabula.read_pdf(file, pages = "all", multiple_tables = True)`**

I get `attributeError: module 'tabula' has no attribute 'read_pdf'.`

I tried most of solutions found on web, installing `tabula-py` rather than only `tabula` also does not help.
Any clue?

Many thanks!

Comment: Uninstall tabula and tabula-py then reinstall tabula-py

Comment: Tried, that does not help unluckily

Comment: Are you installing into the same version of Python you are using ? 2/3 etc ?

Comment: I assume so, I have only 3 installed ...

Comment: what is the output of ```pip --version```

Comment: pip 19.2.3 is the output

Comment: Im after the entire output like ```pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)``` or is that all you have ?

Comment: pip 19.2.3 from C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

Comment: @Blackchat83 were you able to solve the problem?